# Javascript to make fixed top menu header move up 30px and do so with a smooth transition upon scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, header, fixed

I am new to Javascript.

This is what I have so far:
https://journeysendstudios.com/ospitest/

( just focusing on the header )

What I've done so far is that when you scroll down, the green portion disappears and the black portion moves up to top: 0. This is working, but of course it looks very abrupt. ( not sure if this is the most optimal way to achieve this either ) But I am trying to figure out how to ease the transition? Should I do that with CSS or in the script? How can I ease the transition of the box moving up and down from top:0?

This is the Java I am using:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("MenuShrink").style.top = "0px";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("MenuShrink").style.top = "30px";

  }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also, when I add the CSS element: transition: all 0.5s ease; the green bar disappears when the page is reloaded and only appears when you scroll back up...

Comment: You already have a transition for `top` on `MenuShrink` in the link posted above - what do you mean abrupt? Is your intent to have the `MenuShrink` to move up at the same pace as the scroll so that it looks like the green and back move up together?

Comment: hello, sorry i just added the transition: all 0.5s ease; - but do you see how when you load the page, the green is only visibly after you scroll down and go up? i would like to see the green bar when the page first loads.

Comment: the initial value for `top` for `MenuShrink` seems to be `10` - an invalid value on first load - do you have that in your css (`.et_pb_section_1_tb_header` class)? `window.onscroll` would only get called when you start scrolling - and that's why it resets to `30px` or `0px` later on scroll. Setting the value to `30px` in the css, would make the green bar show up

Comment: Hello! Thank you, I think this worked! Can you try it out and see if it works for you too?

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: Thank you so much! (: